# Duality argument to extend operators that commute with translations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, interpolation

For $1 \leq p,q \leq \infty$, let $T$ be a linear operator on the space of Schwarz functions $\mathcal S$ that is bounded from $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ to $L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ and that $T$ commutes with all translations. I have proven that there is a unique $K \in \mathcal S'$ such that $Tf = K*f$ and now am being asked to prove that $T$ can be extended to a bounded linear operator from $L^{q'}$ to $L^{p'}$. I feel like this should follow from a standard duality argument but I've always had a bit of trouble understanding these and am unable to figure this one out.

Comment: What is $\mathcal S$ and what is the basic measure space?

Comment: I have added the context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g \in L^{q'}$ and $f \in L^p$. Note that by H"older, we have
$$\left\vert \int (Tf)g \right\vert \leq \int \vert (Tf)g \vert \leq \Vert Tf \Vert_q \Vert g \Vert_{q'} < \infty,$$
since $T$ is bounded from $L^p$ to $L^q$. So, define $\phi_g(f)$ by
$$\phi_g(f) = \int (Tf)g,$$
which we know from the above is a bounded linear functional. Hence, there exists a unique $g' \in L^{p'}$ such that
$$\phi_g(f) = \int fg'.$$
Define $T$ on $L^{q'}$ by $Tg = g'$. Then, $\Vert Tg \Vert_{p'} = \Vert g' \Vert_{p'} < \infty$.